# I would like to write list of dictionary to txt file

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary, text

[{'Name': 'Syed', 'Age': 17.0, 'DOB': 38034.0, 'Blood group': 'O+', 'mobile no:': 919496589636.0}, {'Name': 'Saurav', 'Age': 16.0, 'DOB': 38391.0, 'Blood group': 'A+', 'mobile no:': 915452587965.0}, {'Name': 'Jinish', 'Age': 18.0, 'DOB': 37654.0, 'Blood group': 'O+', 'mobile no:': 916356254128.0}, {'Name': 'kiran', 'Age': 17.0, 'DOB': 38034.0, 'Blood group': 'O+', 'mobile no:': 919496589636.0}, {'Name': 'Robin', 'Age': 16.0, 'DOB': 38391.0, 'Blood group': 'A+', 'mobile no:': 915452587965.0}, {'Name': 'Ravi', 'Age': 18.0, 'DOB': 37654.0, 'Blood group': 'O+', 'mobile no:': 916356254128.0}]

I am aiming to get an output of this way in .txt

```
Name     Age      DOB     Blood group      mobile no:

'Syed'    17.0    38034.0     'O+'         919496589636.0
'Saurav'  16.0    38391.0,    'A+',        915452587965.0
'Jinish'  18.0    37654.0,    'O+',        916356254128.0
'kiran'   17.0    38034.0,    'O+',        919496589636.0
```

I have tried this code,

```
c= ([(d['Name'],d['Age'],d['DOB'],d['Blood group'],d['mobile no:']) for d in dict_list])

#print(c)
 for i in c:
   e=print(i)
g=str(e)
f =open ("D:\\DSUsers\\uie41986\\BIG.txt","w" ) 
f.write(str(g))
f.close()
```

could anybody provide the right code?

Comment: What language is this?  What is wrong with the code you tried?

Comment: python language,  In the text file it is writing"none".

Comment: `print` returns `None`

Answer (score 1):

To write CSV file from the `dict_list`, you can use built-in `csv` module:

```py
import csv

dict_list = [
    {
        "Name": "Syed",
        "Age": 17.0,
        "DOB": 38034.0,
        "Blood group": "O+",
        "mobile no:": 919496589636.0,
    },
    {
        "Name": "Saurav",
        "Age": 16.0,
        "DOB": 38391.0,
        "Blood group": "A+",
        "mobile no:": 915452587965.0,
    },
    {
        "Name": "Jinish",
        "Age": 18.0,
        "DOB": 37654.0,
        "Blood group": "O+",
        "mobile no:": 916356254128.0,
    },
    {
        "Name": "kiran",
        "Age": 17.0,
        "DOB": 38034.0,
        "Blood group": "O+",
        "mobile no:": 919496589636.0,
    },
    {
        "Name": "Robin",
        "Age": 16.0,
        "DOB": 38391.0,
        "Blood group": "A+",
        "mobile no:": 915452587965.0,
    },
    {
        "Name": "Ravi",
        "Age": 18.0,
        "DOB": 37654.0,
        "Blood group": "O+",
        "mobile no:": 916356254128.0,
    },
]

with open("data.csv", "w") as f_out:
    fieldnames = ["Name", "Age", "DOB", "Blood group", "mobile no:"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(dict_list)
```

Creates `data.csv`:

```
Name,Age,DOB,Blood group,mobile no:
Syed,17.0,38034.0,O+,919496589636.0
Saurav,16.0,38391.0,A+,915452587965.0
Jinish,18.0,37654.0,O+,916356254128.0
kiran,17.0,38034.0,O+,919496589636.0
Robin,16.0,38391.0,A+,915452587965.0
Ravi,18.0,37654.0,O+,916356254128.0
```

Screenshot from LibreOffice:

[image]